# Failed to resolve '@wasmer/wasi/lib/bindings/browser' from './index.js'

Tags: javascript, webassembly, parceljs

I am trying to run the hello-world program in Wasmer on windows which is in Javascript (Wasmer is an open-source runtime for executing WebAssembly on the Server). But I am getting the below error. You can have a look at the code: [Hello-World](https://github.com/wasmerio/docs.wasmer.io/tree/master/integrations/js/wasi/browser/examples/hello-world)

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234
× Build failed.

@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '@wasmer/wasi/lib/bindings/browser' from './index.js'

  C:\Users\msi\docs.wasmer.io\integrations\js\wasi\browser\examples\hello-world\index.js:2:29
    1 | import { WASI } from '@wasmer/wasi/lib'
  > 2 | import browserBindings from '@wasmer/wasi/lib/bindings/browser'
  >   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import { WasmFs } from '@wasmer/wasmfs'
    4 |
```

Comment: i guess you are missing the @wasmer/wasi dependency, or it's the wrong version, try a newer demo if you have one

Comment: run npm install?

Comment: npm install is giving error

Answer (score 0):

That linked hello world example is using [an old version of `@wasmer/wasi`.](https://github.com/wasmerio/docs.wasmer.io/blob/e75f30f61a3fcc0bed0573a0fcfeeabdd93d9d8d/integrations/js/wasi/browser/examples/hello-world/package.json#L21)

You need to either downgrade your version, or [follow the up-to-date docs](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-js)